# Error: view.hlp(...) is not a function in jsrender

Tags: jquery, html, templates, if-statement, jsrender

I am using jsrender to map the templates in grid. I am calling a method inside jsrender if condition like below,

```
@section scripts{
    $.views.helpers({
        isMobile: function () {
            return ("@IsMobileDevice" == "False" && (window.innerWidth < 1200));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{if ~isMobile()}}
        <li class="show">Show</li>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

But I am getting an error:

> view.hlp(...) is not a function.

Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar issue and wrong in my helper method is that I have called my helper method before it is initialization.  see below example

**Wrong code**

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender">
{{if ~isMobile()}}
    <li class="show">Show</li>
{{/if}}

 $.views.helpers({
    isMobile: function () {
        return ("@IsMobileDevice" == "False" && (window.innerWidth < 1200));
    }
});
</script>
```

**Right Code**

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender">
$.views.helpers({
    isMobile: function () {
        return ("@IsMobileDevice" == "False" && (window.innerWidth < 1200));
    }
});
{{if ~isMobile()}}
    <li class="show">Show</li>
{{/if}}
</script>
```

Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to help when you post Razor code. You need to show the code that is loaded into the browser, not the server code, since your question is about client-side JsRender.

It seems that the `isMobile` helper is not a function. Perhaps your helper definition code is not getting loaded in the browser before running the template rendering code - or there is an issue/bug in the server code so that the `isMobile` helper is registered in the browser, but is not a function.